# Mysql query not work using and oprator

Tags: and-operator

When using the following mysql query:

```
select * from gc_product_attribute where (attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') and (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71')
```

The values exist in the table but nothing gets return

table below

```
attribute_id | text
 30          |  62
 35          |  71
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to return the items that have (attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') **and the items** that have (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71').

This is different from retrieving the items that have (attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') **and have** (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71')

It can be expressed in two ways :

- retrieve the items that satisfy X and also the items that satisfy Y : **UNION**

  `select * from gc_product_attribute where (attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') UNION select * from gc_product_attribute where (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71')`
- retrieve the items that satisfy either X or Y : **OR**

  `select * from gc_product_attribute where (attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') OR (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71')`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for this

(attribute_id = 30 AND text like '62') **OR** (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '71')

surely there is no row with attribute_id both 30 and 35.

Comment: both attribute_id 30 and 35 and both text 62 and 71 exist respectively.

Comment: yes but not for any given one row at a time, this is why your query is not returning any row. Use the OR as I suggested above and it should return two rows if your have two rows as following     1. combination of attribute_id 30 and text 62        2. combination of attribute_id 35 and text 71

Answer (score 0):

please try:

```
select * 
from gc_product_attribute 
where attribute_id=30 
AND text like '%62%' 
OR (attribute_id = 35 AND text like '%71%')
```